# Cannot launch the Groovy Console

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I have just did a fresh install of Groovy 2.4.3 in OSX 10.10.3 by means of the [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) tool.
I also installed, using GVM, related libraries and tools such as groovyserv, grails and gradle.
The Java version I am using is 1.8.0_25.

Everything seems fine with the exception that I cannot start the Groovy Console by means of the command `groovyConsole` since I keep obtaining this exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:160)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.parse(XmlSettingsParser.java:150)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.load(IvySettings.java:417)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings$load.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.<init>(GrapeIvy.groovy:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.getInstance(Grape.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1844)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3734)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:293)
    at groovy.ui.ConsoleIvyPlugin.addListener(ConsoleIvyPlugin.groovy:41)
    at groovy.ui.ConsoleIvyPlugin$addListener.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at groovy.ui.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:239)
    at groovy.ui.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:244)
    at groovy.ui.Console.main(Console.groovy:206)
    ... 6 more
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Just a wild hunch: it might have something to do with `.ivy2` or `.java/.userPrefs/groovy/prefs.xml`. Try `mv .ivy2 .ivy2.backup && .java/.userPrefs/groovy/prefs.xml .java/.userPrefs/groovy/prefs.xml.backup` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Well I have not even installed Ivy so I do not think that may be the cause.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess part of Groovy (Grapes perhaps) uses Ivy. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/issues/95

Comment: Do you have any weird classpath set up in your environment? Do you have anything pointing to an old version of groovy? Anything like Java_home set to point to weird places?

Comment: Hi @Tim. The problem indeed was that I had in my CLASSPATH something pointing to a jar including the package 'javax.xml.parsers' for some reason. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Sergio glad we got it sorted, and done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this one before and it was due to an environment classpath variable set to point to an invalid jar

Answer (score 0):

I had also same issue. In my case JAVA_HOME path was wrong. So I set JAVA_HOME then its working without any problem.

[image]

After setting JAVA_HOME, its launched:
[image]